# How to install pod? It's not getting installed in my application

Tags: ios, cocoapods

How to do pod installation? I tried it out but nothing is happening in my swift application.

[image]

> pod requires active gem version 2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, gems are ruby script. To install it go to your terminal and type then you would need to provide your password.

> sudo gem install cocoapods

after it was installed to your xcode project where you want to add or use the pod , and make sure the xcode project is closed.

so if I wanted to go my project in the desktop in the terminal

> cd Desktop && cd name_of_project

Then now type:

> pod init

then you open the pod file

> open Podfile  (it will open inside of a text editor)

now remove the `#` in front of  **platform :ios, '8.0'** and **use_frameworks**

In between the

`target "name_of project" do`

// place the source and the pod

`end`

save the file then go back to the same terminal and type:

> pod install

wait until it finished then go your xcode (not to your terminal) project then open `.xcworkspace` everytime you want to access your project

Answer (score 0):

You need CocoaPods to be installed in your system.

Go to Console,
and type:

> sudo gem install cocoapods --verbose

If you get any warning(s)/error(s) then, please update the question with the log showing ther warning(s)/error(s).

Kind Regards,
Suman Adhikari

Answer (score 0):

For me I *down graded* the pod to an earlier version and then it worked perfectly well.